# How to fix the following issue - SystemException: javax/activation/DataSource?

Tags: java, jaxb, java-11

We are going through a migration from java 8 to java 11, and are currently stuck on an issue  which seems like a javax library problem. I found out that javax.activation was excluded from java 9 and onwards so we added the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

, but the issue persists. Any other thoughts on what could be wrong here?

```
022-11-04 15:30:56,505 [][][][][ERROR] - javax/activation/DataSource
2022-11-04 15:30:56,506 [][][][][ERROR] - [java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method), 
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017), 
java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174), 
java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555), 
java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458), 
java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452), 
java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method), 
java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451), 
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589), 
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522), 
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:538), 
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522), 
com.edb.finance.appl.document.livecycleproxy.LiveCycleProxyClient.mapLiveCycleRequestToDocumentInputData(LiveCycleProxyClient.java:269), 
com.edb.finance.appl.document.livecycleproxy.LiveCycleProxyClient.createLiveCycleProxyServiceRequest(LiveCycleProxyClient.java:231), 
com.edb.finance.appl.document.livecycleproxy.LiveCycleProxyClient.produceDocuments(LiveCycleProxyClient.java:84), 
com.edb.finance.appl.document.livecycleproxy.LiveCycleProxyClient.produceDocument(LiveCycleProxyClient.java:79), 
com.edb.finance.appl.document.livecycleproxy.LiveCycleProxyClient.produceDocument(LiveCycleProxyClient.java:64), 
com.edb.finance.appl.document.components.decisionreport.dao.DecisionReportDAO.generateDecisionReport(DecisionReportDAO.java:75), 
com.edb.finance.appl.document.components.decisionreport.business.DecisionReport.generateDecisionReport(DecisionReport.java:91), 
com.edb.finance.appl.document.components.decisionreport.business.DecisionReportProxy.generateDecisionReport(DecisionReportProxy.java:44), 
com.edb.finance.appl.document.components.decisionreport.business.report.StandardReportPdfGenerator.generateStandardPdfCaseReport(StandardReportPdfGenerator.java:110), 
com.edb.finance.appl.document.components.decisionreport.business.report.DecisionReportGenerator.storeAllCaseReports(DecisionReportGenerator.java:109), 
com.edb.finance.appl.decisionextended.components.decisionextended.business.ejb.DecisionExtendedEJB.updateRecommendationOnCaseAndGenerateReport(DecisionExtendedEJB.java:3990), 
com.edb.finance.appl.decisionextended.components.decisionextended.business.ejb.DecisionExtendedProxy.updateRecommendationOnCaseAndGenerateReport(DecisionExtendedProxy.java:346), 
com.edb.finance.appl.decisionextended.components.decisionextended.business.ServiceHandler.updateRecommendationOnCaseAndGenerateReport(ServiceHandler.java:83), 
com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.jointlimit.ws.resources.jointlimit.JointLimitService.createRecommendationInCase(JointLimitService.java:921), 
com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.jointlimit.ws.resources.jointlimit.JointLimitService.createRecommendationForCase(JointLimitService.java:706), 
com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.jointlimit.ws.resources.jointlimit.JointLimitService.createRecommendationsAllCasesRelatedToGroup(JointLimitService.java:685), 
com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.jointlimit.ws.resources.jointlimit.JointLimitService.createRecommendation(JointLimitService.java:643), 
com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.jointlimit.ws.resources.jointlimit.JointLimitService.runCreateRecommendationJob(JointLimitService.java:517), 
com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.jointlimit.ws.resources.jointlimit.JointLimitService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2a40bb74.invoke(<generated>), 
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218), 
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779), 
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163), 
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750), 
org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115), 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264), 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128), 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628), 
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)]
2022-11-04 15:30:56,506 [][][][][ERROR] - javax/activation/DataSource
2022-11-04 15:30:56,508 [][][][][ERROR] - Service threw exception
com.edb.finance.common.exception.SystemException: javax/activation/DataSource
                at com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.jointlimit.ws.resources.jointlimit.JointLimitService.runCreateRecommendationJob(JointLimitService.java:525)
                at com.evry.fs.lending.ecp.jointlimit.ws.resources.jointlimit.JointLimitService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2a40bb74.invoke(<generated>)
                at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
                at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: "dao" and "springframework" sounds *very like* `javax.sql.DataSource` ... can you exclude this misunderstanding/wrong import?

Comment: `javax.activation` has been [superseded by `jakarta.activation`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jakarta_EE_Maven_Coordinates)

Comment: @Holger So you think substituting javax.activation dependency in pom with jakarta.activation should solve this ?

Comment: switching to jakarta.activation did not help

Comment: @xerx593 could you elaborate a bit on your answer?

Comment: I think, there’s no way around also updating the software.